# .NET Framework required for all programs made with visual studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, frameworks

I ask because it takes about 20-30 min to install the .NET Framework on a machine and I am just wondering if my small little program actually needs it. I guess I'm gonna see if I can not include it and how that works out.

Comment: yes, you need the .NET framework for managed applications written with VS

Answer (score 4):

If you write application in unmanaged C++ you will not need .NET framework.

But frankly, newer Windows operating systems already include .NET Framework:

Version 3.0 of the .NET Framework is included with Windows Server 2008 and Windows Vista

Version 3.5 is included with Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2

Version 4.5 is included with Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012

and most of other computers out there will have it already installed by means of windows update, or other applications requiring .NET.

Answer (score 0):

you only need the .net framework if you target it in your application

you can write javascript, Office, c++, SQL server etc applications that would not need the .net framework.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/hh487283.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct answer to your question, but you should note that most versions of windows come with the .NET framework pre-installed.

See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71390/which-operating-systems-come-with-net

If you want to write an application with C# or VB.NET, you may way to try to target .NET framework version 2 or 3. Anyone running Vista or higher should be able to run your app without installing the .NET framework.